Wired connection randomly drops after upgrade to 24.04
After upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04, the wired connection randomly drops after sometime. The network icon shows that it is still connected normally, but I can't access the internet through a browser, or if I try to ping www.google.com through the terminal, for example it doesn't work.
I have to unplug the ethernet cable and plug it back in in order to fix it.
Also, because my computer doesn't have an ethernet port, I use an ethernet network adapter, however I never had any issues with it with the previous version of ubuntu.
